# Button not launching to new activity

Tags: android, listview

I have been trying to make a ListView which will have image, textviews and buttons.

I am trying to get the buttons to start a new activity by using the code

[image: button code]

but when I use

> Intent intent = new Intent(MyListAdapter.this, Login.class);

I get the error `Cannot Resolve constructor intent error`.

And in the very next line

> startActivity(intent);

I get the `error cannot resolve method startactivity`

I wanted to ask how can I get it to launch the activity I want? I have put the full code below

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

---

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hero> {

//the list values in the List of type hero
List<Hero> heroList;

//activity context
Context context;

//the layout resource file for the list items
int resource;

//constructor initializing the values
public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Hero> heroList) {
    super(context, resource, heroList);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.heroList = heroList;
}

//this will return the ListView Item as a View
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    //we need to get the view of the xml for our list item
    //And for this we need a layoutinflater
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    //getting the view
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null, false);

    //getting the view elements of the list from the view
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView textViewName = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textViewTeam = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTeam);
    Button test = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

    //getting the hero of the specified position
    Hero hero = heroList.get(position);

    //adding values to the list item
    imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(hero.getImage()));
    textViewName.setText(hero.getName());
    textViewTeam.setText(hero.getTeam());

    //adding a click listener to the button to remove item from the list

    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyListAdapter.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    return view;


}
```

Comment: you need to pass context to adapter class from your activity and start next activity by this context.startActivity(intent); added : Intent(.context, Login.class);

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 1):

`Intent` takes first argument as `Context`. Since `Adapter` is not child class of `Context` you can not directly use `this`. You have to use `context` which is passed as a Argument. Modify your code as follows.

```
tx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, Login.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It fixed the constructor error but the startactivity method cannot be resolved is still there edit:nvm forgot to put context over there as well, sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the params you put inside Intent's constructor is not correct. Use `Context` instead.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(yourContext, Login.class);
yourContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to startActivity with Context. Where we can get context in Adapter? Check below:

```
final Context mContext = test.getContext();

test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Login.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```